# Tried upgrading rails and its stuck on v2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I did the whole `gem install rails` and it downloaded version 3.0.5 but when I hit `rails -v` it says `2.3.5`.

How do I swap?

Comment: This doesn't answer the immediate question, but you may wish to look into [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/), which has a "gemset" feature to help keep your gems nice and segregated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't just a "Swap" of versions you have to upgrade rails, a lot has changed I recommend watching a series of [screencasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1)  about upgrading rails

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your path to determine where it is sourcing the 'rails' command from ?

Items to check:

1. PATH setting from your login environment  (e.g *% env | grep PATH*)
2. Location of the commands (e.g *% locate rails*)

This may clarify where the Rails command is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you might want to try [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). It's a real gem to work with if you need to target different versions and combinations of Rubies and Gems (including Rails).